# How to pass "values" between C# and C++ dll

Tags: c#, visual-c++

I have a dll project with C++ like:

```
_declspec(dllexport) bool __stdcall cppPage1(char* Input, char* Output)
{
    string str1 = Input;
    //blablabla
    strcat(Output, "Result#as#a#string");
}
```

And in C#, I use this with:

```
[DllImport("ReportContent.dll")]
extern static bool cppPage1()
public void Page1()
{
    StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("1#3", 10000);
    StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder("", 10000);
    cppPage1(s1, s2);
}
```

As shown above, I "get" some RAM with `StringBuilder` where C# and C++ both can read/write. C++ read `Input` from RAM and did calculating logics and write to `Output` which is also in RAM so that C# can get the result.
Let `StringBuilder.Length = 10000` to make sure that enough in most situations.

I don't think it is a good practice to consider RAM in C#.
What is the right way of communicating between C# and C++?

Comment: +1 most fuzzy use of the word RAM of the day

Comment: @sehe or should I say Memory or what?

Comment: Probably. What you really are getting is a memory address (= a pointer to memory), that you than choose to dereference. The memory was always there and you didn't need to do an interop call to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should translate the signature from C to C# using P/Invoke marshaling rules. There are a number of tools to help you with that.

Here is the documentation

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx)
- http://pinvoke.net/
- http://www.red-gate.com/pinvoke/download P/Invoke addin

Comment: I try to use something like `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)` and it works fine. Thanks.